# How can I publish to the Apple app store my expo application?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I have finished to write a react-native application written with the help of expo SDK and I want to build my final `.apk` and `.ipa` for testing them with real devices.

During the development, I have used one `iPhone 6` and one `Galaxy S9` real devices using the `expo` application.

So far, I managed to build from Debian the signed `apk` but I didn't find a way to get an `.ipa` from my Debian linux system.

I can't have xcode installed but if needed I can rent a mac online and submit the ipa from there.

I have already followed those guides:

- https://docs.expo.io/distribution/building-standalone-apps/
- https://docs.expo.io/distribution/app-signing/
- https://customersupport.doubledutch.me/hc/en-us/articles/360001189514-iOS-How-to-Create-a-Distribution-Certificate

[This guy](https://forums.expo.io/t/build-expo-ios-without-mac-and-ios-phone/27426) says:

> Is it possible…sure. The only thing a Mac is needed for is XCode for actually uploading your IPA to AppStore. I do not own a MAC personally, so I rent an online one via MacInCloud.

What are the steps to build an `.ipa` on [expo](https://expo.io/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super simple if you are using the managed workflow (not sure if this is the case?).

```
expo build:ios
```

You will then get a link which will allow you to download the .ipa once it has been built on the expo servers.

Open your MacInCloud mac, download the .ipa from the link provided, and then upload it to the AppStore using the Transporter app.

Comment: So you need to check your app.json file. It thinks your bundle identifier is com.myapp.www which is definitely incorrect - you need to change this to the identifier you will be using on the app store. Once you have updated it correctly, you should be able to proceed with the build - it will ask you a couple of questions regarding credential management etc. Just go through your app.json entries and ensure they are all correct before trying again.

Comment: It could possibly be the issue - at the very least he should add you as a developer on the apple account, you would need this to publish to the app store anyway.